# Formatting range selector in highcharts asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am working on highcharts in asp.net MVC 
So far i have achieved [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzTUQ.jpg)
Here i first select the serial number then i select the start date, end date then i click on show chart, on click it shows all the data within the time range and that is correct because the time (from - to) is correct, and the navigator bar is having all the trend within the range.

Now i want to do is that the navigator will have all the trend of selected serial number but i will show only the data within the time range selected

Also in the attached picture the red box is showing date from-to which is correct as i early mentioned it but it's format is not good the date is coming out of the textbox i want the date to fit in. is there any solution for it ?

**Note**
I want the format and navigation trend just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unKWJ.jpg)
Link is attached in the comment

I hope i have given enough information and hoping to get replies soon

Any help would be appreciated

**UPDATED CODE**

```
   var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container1',
            type: 'column',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            panning: true,
            pankey: 'shift',
            resetZoomButton: {
                position: {
                    //align: 'right', // by default
                    //verticalAlign: 'top', // by default
                    x: -10,
                    y: 350,
                    //height: 25
                },

                relativeTo: 'chart'
            }
        },
        navigator: {
            series: {

            },
            enabled: true,
            adaptToUpdatedData: true,
            height: 30,                

        },

        rangeSelector: {
            buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
                fill: 'none',
                stroke: 'none',
                'stroke-width': 0,
                r: 8,
                style: {
                    color: '#039',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                    },
                    select: {
                        fill: '#039',
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    }
                    // disabled: { ... }
                }
            },
            enabled: true,
            inputBoxWidth: 160,
            inputStyle: {
                color: '#039',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            labelStyle: {
                color: 'black',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            buttons: [{
                type: 'minute',
                count: 60 * 6,
                text: '6h'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1d'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 7,
                text: '7d'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }]
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                turboThreshold: 50000
            }

        },
        title: {
            text: 'Energy vs Date & Time',
            style: {
                //color: '#FF00FF',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                //fontSize: '12px'
                //sfont: 'bold 200px Verdana, sans-serif',
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            //  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            type: 'datetime',
            // max: new Date().getTime(),
            //labels: {

            // //   format: {value:}
            //    style: {
            //        fontSize: '13px',
            //        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            //    }
            //}
        }, yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Energy (kWh)',
                style: {
                    //color: '#FF00FF',
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    //sfont: 'bold 200px Verdana, sans-serif',
                }
            }

        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Energy kWh',
            color: 'green',
            data: arry_kwh,
        }]


    });
```

Half of my work is done now i only want is that the navigator bar should have all the data series and it will show the data only what i have searched in the time range

Comment: here is the link for jsfiddle for which i want the same format
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/allbuttonsenabled-true/

Comment: Have you read already Highcharts .net docs http://www.highcharts.com/dotnet

Comment: Yes now i am able to do what i want but i want to pass the whole series in navigator bar see the updated code